# Hovering on right part of window, content go to the left

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have all my images in a row, that is larger than most screens.

So like you can see in the code below, I have the images in a loop with jQuery thanks to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9500196/jquery-hover-effect-image-preview-going-out-of-the-browsers-window).

But I should like to do 2 things, first adapt the speed of the scrolling, but if I try to change something in the jQuery it doesn't work anymore propperly. (I'm a real noob to jQuery and javascript)
The second thing I should like to do, is that it's just starts to scroll from the moment you hover the right part of the page in stead of the whole page.

Another solution I was thinking about, was with arrows, and hovering over or clicking on this arrows would move the image gallery to the right/left. Depending on the arrow of your choice.

The code I have so far is this:

```js
var $content = $('#img-gallery'); // Cache your selectors!
$(".img-gallery").hover( function loop() {
    $content.stop().animate({  marginLeft: '-=1600' }, 5000, 'linear', function(){
        $content.css({ marginLeft : "0px" });
        loop();
    });
}, function stop() {
    $content.stop();
});
```

```css
#img-gallery {
    height:500px;
    overflow-x:auto;
    overflow-y:hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
 padding-left: 50px;
 padding-right: 50px;
}
.column {
    display:inline-block;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width:auto;
 margin-top: 175px;
 margin-bottom:175px;
}
.post {
    height:150px;
}
.img-gal {
 height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="img-gallery" class="default-skin img-gallery" oncontextmenu="return false">
 <a href="images/studio/img1.jpg">
     <div class="column">
   <div class="post">
    <img src="http://www.hdwallpapersimages.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/Winter-Tiger-Wild-Cat-Images.jpg" class="img-gal" oncontextmenu="return false"/>
      </div>
  </div>
 </a>
 <a href="images/studio/img2.jpg">
  <div class="column">
   <div class="post">
    <img src="https://www.ucl.ac.uk/news/news-articles/1213/muscle-fibres-heart.jpg" class="img-gal" oncontextmenu="return false"/>
   </div>
  </div>
 </a>
 <a href="images/studio/img3.jpg">
  <div class="column">
   <div class="post">
       <img src="http://www.hdwallpapersimages.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/Winter-Tiger-Wild-Cat-Images.jpg" class="img-gal" oncontextmenu="return false"/>
   </div>
  </div>
 </a>
 <a href="images/studio/img4.jpg">
  <div class="column">
        <div class="post">
    <img src="https://www.ucl.ac.uk/news/news-articles/1213/muscle-fibres-heart.jpg" class="img-gal" oncontextmenu="return false"/>
   </div>
  </div>
 </a>
    <a href="images/studio/img5.jpg">
  <div class="column">
   <div class="post">
    <img src="http://www.hdwallpapersimages.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/Winter-Tiger-Wild-Cat-Images.jpg" class="img-gal" oncontextmenu="return false"/>
   </div>
  </div>
 </a>
 <a href="images/studio/img6.jpg">
  <div class="column">
   <div class="post">
    <img src="https://www.ucl.ac.uk/news/news-articles/1213/muscle-fibres-heart.jpg" class="img-gal" oncontextmenu="return false"/>
   </div>
  </div>
 </a>
 <a href="images/studio/img7.jpg">
  <div class="column">
   <div class="post">
    <img src="http://www.hdwallpapersimages.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/Winter-Tiger-Wild-Cat-Images.jpg" class="img-gal" oncontextmenu="return false"/>
   </div>
  </div>
 </a>
 <a href="images/studio/img8.jpg">
  <div class="column">
   <div class="post">
    <img src="https://www.ucl.ac.uk/news/news-articles/1213/muscle-fibres-heart.jpg" class="img-gal" oncontextmenu="return false"/>
   </div>
  </div>
 </a>
 <a href="images/studio/img9.jpg">
  <div class="column">
   <div class="post">
    <img src="http://www.hdwallpapersimages.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/Winter-Tiger-Wild-Cat-Images.jpg" class="img-gal" oncontextmenu="return false"/>
   </div>
  </div>
 </a>
 <a href="images/studio/img10.jpg">
  <div class="column">
   <div class="post">
    <img src="https://www.ucl.ac.uk/news/news-articles/1213/muscle-fibres-heart.jpg" class="img-gal" oncontextmenu="return false"/>
   </div>
  </div>
 </a>
 <a href="images/studio/img11.jpg">
  <div class="column">
   <div class="post">
    <img src="http://www.hdwallpapersimages.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/Winter-Tiger-Wild-Cat-Images.jpg" class="img-gal" oncontextmenu="return false"/>
   </div>
  </div>
 </a>
 <a href="images/studio/img12.jpg">
  <div class="column">
   <div class="post">
    <img src="https://www.ucl.ac.uk/news/news-articles/1213/muscle-fibres-heart.jpg" class="img-gal" oncontextmenu="return false"/>
   </div>
  </div>
 </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here one quick from me.

```
    var $content = $('#img-gallery'); // Cache your selectors!
$(".buttonLeft").hover( function loop() {
    //speed of animation now is 10000
    $content.stop().animate({  marginLeft: '-=1600' }, 10000 , 'linear', function(){
        $content.css({ marginLeft : "0px" });
        loop();
    });

}, function stop() {
    $content.stop();
});
$(".buttonRight").hover( function loop() {
    //speed of animation now is 10000
    $content.stop().animate({  marginLeft: '+=1600' }, 10000 , 'linear', function(){
        $content.css({ marginLeft : "0px" });
        loop();
    });

}, function stop() {
    $content.stop();
});
```

**Edited:** [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h69e9xxc/)

I hope this will help. Also you can try to make it with little less code.

Answer (score 0):

1) Speed of scrolling

For the speed of scrolling, you need to change the value `5000` in the `animate` object.

This value is the time (in miliseconds) that your gallery need to move from right to left one time, so decrease this number to move faster, increase it to move slower.

2) Hover on right side

I tried to manage something for the hover part, but not sure is exactly the thing you need :
I use a `var` to store the left / not left position of the mouse, and the allow the hover or not :

```
var $content = $('#img-gallery'); // Cache your selectors!
var allowMove = false;
$(".img-gallery").on("mousemove", function (event) {
    allowMove = (event.pageX > ($(window).width() / 2)) ? true : false;
});
$(".img-gallery").hover(function loop() {
    if (allowMove) {
        $content.stop().animate({
            marginLeft: '-=1600'
        }, 2000, 'linear', function () {
            $content.css({
                marginLeft: "0px"
            });
            loop();
        });
    }
}, function stop() {
    $content.stop();
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ghorg12110/c8qo6245/3/)

Comment: Thanks for explaining the speed.
The second is not exactly what I was looking for, that is answered by sddpz